# Spring Data: Projections with native queries to interfaces don't work as expected

Tags: spring-data-jpa

**Native Query Only.**

**Example code:**

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select max(price) as maxPrice from item_history where itme_id = ?1 limit 1;", nativeQuery = true)
    MaxPrice maxPrice(int id);

    interface MaxPrice{
        Integer getMaxPrice();
    }
}
```

**ItemRepository.MaxPrice maxPrice = itemRepository.maxPrice(1);


Why "maxPrice" is not null, but "maxPrice.getMaxPrice();" return null?**